# How import components?

Tags: vue.js

i'm developing my first vue app.
I decided to add it to my project using the html `<script>` tag (so not using the CLI).

Can I use the `import` statement for importing componente stored in `.vue` file?

Comment: You really need to provide some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't import .vue files unless you are using a module bundler like webpack.

However, there are multiple ways of defining a vue component which don't require you to use .vue files.

For example you can define a component in a file like this:

helloWorld.js

```
export default {
  template : `<div>{{ message }}</div>`
  data : () => ({
    message : 'Hello World'
  })
}
```

and then import it like this:

app.js

```
import HelloWorld from 'helloWorld.js';
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
});
```

Just remember to add `type="module"` when you import your js files into your html:

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <hello-world></hello-world>
  </div>
  <script type="module" src="helloWorld.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to select this as the correct answer if it worked!